# What is the quick meaning of the terms print and return in Python?

Tags: python, printing, return

I'm learning some new things, and I cannot figure out the whole return process from reading my texts and looking online. I believe I need it explained to me once for me to wrap my head around it.

The code here works as intended; I would like the user to input a number, then if less than 0, print 0, if greater than or equal to zero print the number.

```
def positiveNumber():
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num <= 0:
        print("0")
    else:
        print(num)

positiveNumber()
```

What isn't working is where I just want the function to return the values, then only give me the answer when I call the function.

```
def positiveNumber():
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return num

positiveNumber()
print(num)
```

My shell keeps telling me "name 'num' is not defined".

Comment: `num` is a local variable that only exists in `positiveNumber()`. You might be looking for `print(positiveNumber())`.

Comment: might be worth to check out "scope of variables": https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variable-scope-and-lifetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num` is a [**local variable**](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) that only exists in `positiveNumber()`.

You want:

```
print(positiveNumber())
```

Comment: So, would this be saying that I don't really call my function? Instead I'm just printing the result of it?

Comment: @Genoxidus That is incorrect. You ARE calling the function. When the function terminates, it returns its return value, which is then printed.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `num` is defined within your function. It thus only exists in the "scope" of the function.
When you're calling the function, you should try

```
a = positiveNumber()
print(a)
```

The returned value is something that you should assign to a variable in order to use.
Your function is sending back the value of `num`
So you can either

```
print(positiveNumber())
```

Or you can store it somewhere, and then use that.
This happens because the name `num` only exists inside the function, it's computed and the **VALUE** is being returned. So you can either directly print this **VALUE**  or you could store it in some variable and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked:

```
def positiveNumber():
    num = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    if num <= 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return num

print(positiveNumber())
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank yo for the advice. I have updated the answer I used with the check mark.